# batch edit mp4 metadata terminal

Tags: video, metadata, batch-processing, mp4

**Problem statement:** I need an way to batch-add mp4 metadata from a CSV via Ruby or a Linux / OS X Terminal CLI app.

**What I've tried:** Tried Atomic Parsley (does not appear to have been updated to support Cast/Directors/etc fields) and SublerCLI (does not appear to facilitate quick optimization - read: process the file to place the updated info atom before the data atom - on multiple cores).

**Need:** Do you know of an updated CLI solution I can use for batch-adding metadata (at a minimum ... **Name**, **Genre**, **Release Date**, **Long Description**, **Cast**, **Copyright**, and **Media Kind** fields) and **optimizing** the file utilizing full processing power of a multi-core CPU?

**Further info:** The metadata is from an old system that stored metadata in HTML/XML files. The metadata has been parsed from the files using Nokogiri and put into a CSV.